# Apply minimum_should_match in Elasticsearch-DSL to inner scope

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have such code in `Elasticsearch-DSL`:

```
for family_samples_q in qs:
  genotypes_q |= family_samples_q

Search().query('bool', filter=[genotypes_q], minimum_should_match=2)
```

Unfortunately `minimum_should_match` applies to the outer scope, to `filter` (and others if I defined, say, `must`, another `should` queries, etc.) but not to inner one, not to `genotypes_q` list of queries. How to fix that?